# AIC for probability density function

Tags: r

I want code in r on how to calculate the  AIC     CAIC      BIC     HQIC         W         A of this this pdf

```
f(x) = ((a*log(b))/(x^2*b - x^2))*exp(-(a/x))*b^(exp(-(a/x))) and cdf F(x)= (b^(exp(-(a/x))) - 1)/(b - 1)
```

using these data

```
1 11 4 32 23 45 115 37 29 71 39 23 21 37 20 12 13 135
49 32 64 40 77 97 97 85 10 27 7 48 35 61 79 63 16 80
108 20 52 82 50 64 59 39 9 16 78 35 66 122 89 110 44 28
65 22 59 23 31 44 21 9 45 168 73 76 118 84 85 96 78 73
91 47 32 20 23 21 24 44 21 28 9 13 46 18 13 24 16 13
23 36 7 14 30 14 18 20
```

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Please at least define the variables in your formula.

Comment: a > 0, b > 2  are constant and x is a variable